# How to pass configuration parameters to angular libraries?

Tags: angular, configuration, bootstrapping, angular-library, angular2-bootstrapping

I am building a wrapper library 'auth-lib' for some existing(and out of my control) authentication libraries(for example [keycloak-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular) ).
The authentication libraries I'm wrapping need to get initialized with configuration parameters during app initialization or bootstrapping which works when hard coding the configurations inside my Wrapper library but I can't get it to work with injection or forRoot from a sample application for my wrapper library.

How to pass the configuration parameters from my sample application through my wrapper library to the authentication libraries?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can pass the configuration from App.Module using `forRoot` to your Library Module.

Try like this:

**App.module.ts**

```
 imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      AuthLibModule.forRoot({
        configuration: {configA : "abc", configB : "xyz"}
      })
   ]
```

**AuthLibModule.module.ts**

```
export class AuthLibModule{ 
  static forRoot(configuration): ModuleWithProviders {
    console.log(configuration);
    return {
      ngModule: AuthLibModule,
      providers: [AuthLibService,{provide: 'config', useValue: configuration}]
    };
  }
}
```

**AuthLibService.service :**

```
export class AuthLibService{

  constructor(@Inject('config') private config:any) {
    console.log(config)
   }
}
```

Comment: When I did that in a separate project, it worked; but moving it into my project doesn't so there is a problem with my project setup that I will need to figure out. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Hey @Adrita - when I do this Argument Type (configuration: {configB: string, configA: string}} is not assignable to parameter type Routes.  I've tried this many times and can't get around this error - something seems wrong with my syntax - any thoughts?  I can post more code if that helps.  Thank you

Comment: @Voltan Can you share your code in stackbiltz

Comment: @Adrita - thank you for response, Intellij was giving me a bogus error.  All working now, so I'll close this.

Comment: @Voltan Great. If this helped you please upvote :)